# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 keyboard layout panel indicator missing

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, mate, ubuntu-mate, mate-panel

After upgrade to 20.04 and resetting the panel settings I can no longer see the keyboard layout indicator on the panel. Not sure about exact steps to reproduce it. I suppose, you can remove the "Indicator Applet Complete" and re-add it to the panel. The layout switching works fine.

Adding screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Removing and re-adding is not working for me, I still cannot get the keyboard-layout switching functionality to return. This is fairly awkward as I *do* need to switch between a couple different layouts with some frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using MATE Tweak. You can install MATE tweak using:

```
$ sudo apt install mate-tweak
```

Type mate tweak in the search tool bar, go to panel and select a different layout. 
It might appear.

MATE tweak → Panel → different layout.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing anything new you might want to check how many languages are available for typing. Check Settings - Keyboard - Input sources. If only one language is in the list, language panel is not displayed. In my case, after adding additional languages the panel appeared.